# What is the best way to display categories in a Jekyll site?

Tags: html, blogs, jekyll, octopress

I have got a small blog that uses Jekyll. Now I want to add some more functionality to my post layout. I want to add this line on top of every post:

```
Tagged with category1, category2, ...
```

What is the best way to achieve this. Can someone help me with the Jekyll code that I have to add in my html file?

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty easy with [Liquid filters](https://github.com/shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers). In your `_layout/post.html` template, add this line where you want the output:

```
Tagged with {{ page.categories | join: ', ' }}
```

This will *join* your list of categories into a comma-space delimited string. You can get fancier and link to the categories if you set up an Archive by Category index using a plugin.

Be sure that you have added categories to your individual files in `_posts/` using the [YAML Front Matter](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/YAML-Front-Matter) syntax:

```
---
layout: post
title: Title
categories:
- cat1
- cat2
- etc...
---
```

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks for the tip! Really falling in-love with Liquid.

Comment: I use a leaner one-line syntax for multiple categories: `categories: [one, another, two words]`